# Confusion about solving linear second order ode with boundary condition.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the following problem in a textbook I have to solve. Sadly I'm not sure what to do.

Given is $y^"(x)=\lambda y(x)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I'm supposed to find a solutions $(y(x), \lambda)$ with $x \in [0, \pi]$ and the boundary conditions a) $y(0)=y(\pi)=1$ and b) $y'(0)=y'(\pi)=0$. I'm not sure if a and b are two diffrent tasks or one and the same.

I started with the basic approach of $y=e^{\mu x}, \, y'=\mu e^{\mu x}, \, y"=\mu^2 e^{\mu x}$.

I got  $y=C_1e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}+\frac{C_2}{e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}}$ and $y'=\sqrt{\mu} C_1e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}+\frac{\sqrt{\mu} C_2}{e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}}$

Then I first used the left boundary and then the right boundary and got two $C_1$ and two $C_2$. I set them to be equal and came to the solution $(y(x)=1, \lambda = 0)$.

Does this make sense? Or should I treat a and b as two diffrent boundary value problems?

Comment: check if the following inverse Fourier transform fulfill your requirements $$y(t)=\mathbf{F}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{iw^2(e^{-i\pi w}-1)}{w(w^2-\lambda)}\right\}$$ if works, tag me and I show you how I got it. I am not really sure if its right, but maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your general solution $$y=C_1e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}+\frac{C_2}{e^{\sqrt{\mu}x}}$$
has two arbitrary coefficients, that is, you need two conditions to specify then. So 'a' and 'b' will result in two different solutions. They are different tasks.